# Using Pig to store data to Hbase error when using Hue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, hue

My CDH version is 5.1.2, my Hbase version is 0.98.1, my Hue version is 3.6.0. I executed this pig script to load data from Hbase in Hue

```
c = LOAD 'hbase://analyze_block_v1' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('d:*', '-loadKey true');
dump c;
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormat.
```

Follow a guide on google, i uploaded all `hbase*.jars` from folder hbase library to `user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20140822104613/pig`, and add the following statement to the top of script:

```
set hbase.zookeeper.quorum 'localhost'
```

I still got the same error.

Continue google, I found the guide at GetHue and the guide from Cloudera website

Those guide told me that i must add these statement to top of pig script :

```
register /usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-<ZooKeeper_version>-cdh<CDH_version>.jar

register /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-<HBase_version>-cdh<CDH_version>-security.jar

set hbase.zookeeper.quorum 'localhost'
```

The problem is i can't find `hbase-0.98.1-cdh5.1.2-security.jar` in my Hbase folder and library. I also downloaded and checked from this link http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/cdh/cdh-5-1-2.html. And there is no `hbase-0.98.1-cdh5.1.2-security.jar` in the hbase folder. I tried download older version hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.5.0 and i can see the file `hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.5.0-security.jar` in the folder.

It seems they don't add the security.jar file in the newer version. I guess because missing this file, the first guide i found can't help

What should i do to fix the error ?

---

**Thank to Romain's support that i can make it work. This is the detail how to do:**

First need to upload these file from Hbase library folder to hdfs. In my case I uploaded them to /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20140822104613/pig

zookeeper.jar

hbase-server-0.98.1-cdh5.1.2.jar

If you use Hue Pig Editor:

Put the jars as a resource in the 'Properties' --> 'Resources' of the script, then just put these statement to top of the script:

REGISTER ./hbase-server-0.98.1-cdh5.1.2.jar;

REGISTER ./zookeper.jar';

Run the script and it will work. In my case i even don't need to register the jar file, it still work. I think just put the jar file in 'properties--> resource' is enough

If you excute the pig script through Hue work flow:

Add File Path to the jar files, then submit the workflow, it will work. It dont need the register and set statement either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc is indeed not up to date but could you just try to include a jar that contains the missing class?

e.g.

```
find /usr/lib/hbase/ -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Hls TableInputFormat {} \;
/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server-tests.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server-0.98.6-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server-0.98.6-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-0.98.6-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-0.98.6-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for helping me !
I used the find command to list files that contain the missing class. Then i tried register each of them but still got the same error.

Example:
REGISTER /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar;
REGISTER /usr/lib/hbase/lib/zookeeper.jar;
set hbase.zookeeper.quorum 'localhost';

c = LOAD 'hbase://analyze_block_v1' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('d:*', '-loadKey true');
dump c;

Comment: Thank to Romain's support that i can make it work. I added the solution in the question.